# Performing many small matrix operations in parallel in OpenCL

Tags: matrix, opencl, gpgpu, linear-algebra, lapack

I have a problem that requires me to do eigendecomposition and matrix multiplication of many (~4k) small (~3x3) square Hermitian matrices. In particular, I need each work item to perform eigendecomposition of one such matrix, and then perform two matrix multiplications. Thus, the work that each thread has to do is rather minimal, and the full job should be highly parallelizable.

Unfortunately, it seems all the available OpenCL LAPACKs are for delegating operations on large matrices to the GPU rather than for doing smaller linear algebra operations inside an OpenCL kernel. As I'd rather not implement matrix multiplcation and [eigendecomposition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401232/calculate-eigenvalues-eigenvectors-of-hundreds-of-small-matrices-using-cuda) for arbitrarily sized matrices in OpenCL myself, I was hoping someone here might know of a suitable library for the job?

I'm aware that OpenCL might be getting built-in matrix operations at some point since the matrix type [is reserved](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/), but that is not really of much use right now. There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306815/opencl-matrix-library) from 2011, but it pretty much just says to roll your own, so I'm hoping the situation has improved since then.

Comment: A few thousand matrix multiplications is nothing, probably not worth transferring data to the GPU and back. We're talking about less than a million FLOP, your CPU can do that in the time it takes to push the matrices and the results into PCIe. I don't know much about eigendecomposition, but I doubt it takes long enough to be worth GPGPU-ing.

Comment: This particular workload has the advantage of requiring very little input to the GPU (the full matrices are never transmitted), and very little output (a reduction step is performed, and only a few numbers are returned). The number of matrices is likely to grow towards 30k for some applications, so I think it should fit a GPU quite well.

Comment: That changes things a bit. If they're already on the GPU, it doesn't make much sense to transfer them *back* for small cheap calculations. Go ahead then :-)

Comment: No, that's exactly what I was thinking. Unforunately OpenCL isn't exactly making it easy for me to do matrix operations on the GPU.

Comment: Do you have any sample code, even just in C?  That would make your question a lot more concrete and might even help generate detailed suggestions, from the many Stack OpenCL practitioners.

Comment: If your CPU is busy doing some other things, then you should send them to GPU using a single thread. I dont know if it uses CPU or DMA for this sending stuff. If it uses DMA, then use it. If not, CPU could finish quick.

Comment: @roybatty: I'm not entirely sure what kind of sample code you would want? I have a single "root" matrix that is transferred to the GPU. This is then modified slightly by each work item before applying eigendecomposition and multiplying with another matrix that is also passed to the kernel. A [reduction](http://developer.amd.com/resources/documentation-articles/articles-whitepapers/opencl-optimization-case-study-simple-reductions/) is then performed to find the modification that yielded the "best" matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, my experience with libraries like LAPACK, fftw, cuFFT, etc. is that when you want to do many really small problems like this, you are better off writing your own for performance. Those libraries are usually written for generality, so you can often beat their performance for specific small problems, especially if you can use unique properties of your particular problem.

I realize you don't want to hear "roll your own" but for this type of problem it is really the best thing to do IMO. You *might* find a library to do this, but considering the code that you *really* want (for performance) will not generalize, I doubt it exists. You'll be looking specifically for code to find the eigenvalues of 3x3 matrices. That's less of a library and more of a random code snippet with a suitable license that you can manipulate to take advantage of your specific problem.

In this specific case, you can find the eigenvalues of a 3x3 matrix with the textbook method using the characteristic polynomial. Remember that there is a relatively simple closed form solution for cubic equations: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots.

While I think it is very likely that this approach would be much faster than iterative methods, it would be wise to verify that if performance is an issue.

Comment: My concern is that the matrices are not always going to be 3x3; they are always square, but may become as large as 8x8, and so a generalized solution would be nice. I'd rather not have to write separate kernels for each matrix size if I can avoid it.

Comment: Then write a code generator that can make the different kernels for you. Tell it the size, it gives back OpenCL kernel source that you compile and run.

Comment: For 2x2, 3x3, and 4x4 matrices, if you have a lot of them to handle in parallel, the solution is unquestionably to use the closed-form decompositions based on the roots of the characteristic polynomial.  As dsharlet suggests, dedicated implementations will be significantly faster than the usual iterative methods, and much more amenable to parallelization.  Unfortunately that isn’t possible for 5x5 and above, so there isn’t a tidy solution here if the sizes go over that threshold.