# Cholesky Decomposition for a large number of small matrices using OpenCL

Tags: matrix, opencl, gpu, gpgpu

My question is similar to what was asked here:[a link] [Performing many small matrix operations in parallel in OpenCL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21049037/performing-many-small-matrix-operations-in-parallel-in-opencl), except that I want to do Cholesky decomposition. Also, my matrices will be going from 15 X 15 to 100 X 100, and I will have upto 100,000 of them. All of the matrices will have the same dimensions.The decomposed matrices will be used further within the GPU.

This paper [a link] http://icl.cs.utk.edu/news_pub/submissions/haidar_iccp.pdf discusses the algorithms at a high level. They use the term batched Cholesky for such a problem (large number of small matrices). The way they have done it is to implement a batched version of all the steps involved in a Cholesky decomposition.

So I am wanting to start with a batched matrix multiplication (since it is one of the steps in a cholesky decomposition). For large matrices, matrix multiplication is done in a blocked manner on a GPU. My question: would it be suitable for the kind of problem I have? Any other suggestions will be helpful. Am a little unsure how to approach this.

Comment: Any kind of re-usable(starting from 3-5 times) variable is fit for local memory optimization (tiling) i think.

Comment: Agreed.  I programmed Levenburg-Marquardt from scratch in OpenCL and it runs 100's of times faster.  Lots of matrix math in that.

Comment: This may be worth checkout out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22479258/cholesky-decomposition-with-openmp